# How to view which cluster worker responded nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, node-cluster

How can someone view which cluster worker responds each time a request is made to the server, in the `console.log`? I am using [express](https://expressjs.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it.. simply add the `console.log(process.pid)` where I handle the requests and that was it :)